# Movement Of Numbers in an array row

Tags: java

I am having trouble visualizing what happens when I have e.g. a row of numbers [1,2,3,4,5] and I either want to shift these numbers to the front of the row or to the back of the row.

Essentially here, I am going through my row, back to front and adding each number. But at the same time, shifting the indexes one to the right in my row.

A code snippet:

```
void addCoordinateRowFront(CoordinateRow rowOfCoordinates) {

        for(int j = rowOfCoordinates.numberOfElements; j > 0; j--) {

            for(int i = numberOfElements; i > 0; i--) {

                newCoordinateArray[i] = newCoordinateArray[i-1];

            }
            newCoordinateArray[0] = rowOfCoordinates.newCoordinateArray[j-1];

            numberOfElements++;
        }

    }

}
```

But I am still not really understanding what is happening.

For instance, if I have a row [1,2,3,4,5] what is the outcome if I add these numbers to the front or to the back of the row?

Comment: If you have trouble visualizing it, try to grab a piece of paper and write down how it would look after each step. That should help.

Comment: If I am writing this down right, then if for instance I shifting these numbers to the front of the row, then eventually I just end up with [1,2,3,4,5] again right?

Comment: You don't provide enough information. From where you took `newCoordinateArray`? How it's initialized (because if it's empty there is no sense in line `newCoordinateArray[i] = newCoordinateArray[i-1];`)? What output do you expect to receive?

Answer (score 1):

`newCoordinateArray[i] = newCoordinateArray[i-1];` is basically shifting the elements to the back, i.e. the element at index 2 will get the value from index 1, then index 1 will get the value from index 0. Finally, index 0 will get the new value.

**Inner loop**

This means, your inner loop would turn `[1,2,3,4,5]` into `[1,1,2,3,4]` if it were correct:

- a[4] = a[3] -> value at index 4 will be the value of index 3, result is `[1,2,3,4,4]`
- a[3] = a[2] -> `[1,2,3,3,4]`
- a[2] = a[1] -> `[1,2,2,3,4]`
- a[1] = a[0] -> `[1,1,2,3,4]`

If you look at the example, you should be able to spot the error in your inner loop:

`int i = numberOfElements` would mean `i = 5` if `numberOfElements` actually means `rowOfCoordinates.numberOfElements` (which would be 5 in the example). However, `a[5] = ...` will cause an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` because the highest index in a 5-element array is 4.

**Outer loop**

Your outer loop moves into index 0 starting at the last element (`a[0] = a[j-1]`). This means after the first run of the inner loop you have `[1,1,2,3,4]` and now `a[0] = a[4]` will result in `[4,1,2,3,4]`.

Now let's look at the other iterations of the outer loop:

- `j = 4` -> inner loop result: `[4,4,1,2,3]`, `a[0] = a[3]` results in `[2,4,1,2,3]` (value at `a[3]` is 2)
- `j = 3` -> inner loop result: `[2,2,4,1,2]`, `a[0] = a[2]` results in `[4,2,4,1,2]` (value at `a[2]` is 4)
- `j = 2` -> inner loop result: `[4,4,2,4,1]`, `a[0] = a[1]` results in `[4,4,2,4,1]` (value at `a[1]` is 4)
- `j = 1` -> inner loop result: `[4,4,4,2,4]`, `a[0] = a[0]` doesn't change anything so the end result would be `[4,4,4,2,4]`

**How to shift in place**

If you want to shift elements in an array without creating a copy of the array, i.e. shift in place, you can do the following:

```
 //replace 1st element
 int replacedIndex = dir;
 int replacedValue = array[replacedIndex];
 array[replacedIndex] = array[0];
     
 //replace all other elements
 for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
     replacedIndex = (replacedIndex + dir) % array.length;           
     int temp = array[replacedIndex];
     array[replacedIndex] = replacedValue;
     replacedValue = temp;
 }
```

What this means is the following:

You shift the first element to its new position which replaces another element. So you keep track of the replaced element and what index it was at. The loop now shifts the replaced element which replaces another one which the next iteration takes care of.

So shifting [A,B,C,D,E] by 2 would mean:

- Initially shift A from index 0 to index 2, so C will be replaced. Result: [A,B,A,D,E].
- C will be shifted from index 2 to index 4: [A,B,A,D,C]
- E will be shifted from index 4 to index 1 (wrap around): [A,E,A,D,C]
- B will be shifted from index 1 to index 3: [A,E,A,B,C]
- D will be shifted from index 3 to index 0 (wrap around): [D,E,A,B,C]

The modulo operator can also be used to allow for larger shifts which basically are brought back into range, i.e. shifting a 4 element array by 13 is the same as shifting it by 1 (13 % 4 = 1).

Negative shifts can be supported by bringing the shift into a positive range by adding the length, i.e. given a 5 element array a shift by -1 (1 to the left) is the same as a shift by 4 (4 to the right).

So you could do this at the start:

```
//copy the initial parameter to keep the original value
int dir = direction;

//shift direction into a positive range
while( dir < 0) {
  dir += array.length;
}

//bring any out-of-range direction back into range
dir %= array.length;
```